# Too few/too many uses of box register in leaders

Tags: leaders

I'm playing a bit with TeX's leaders and ran into a problem I don't understand. Given the following example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\bul{%
    \begingroup
    \setbox0=\hbox to 10pt{\hss\textbullet\hss}%
    \skip0=\wd0 plus 0.5\wd0 minus 0.5\wd0
%    \skip0=10pt plus 5pt minus 5pt  % the same as above
    \cleaders\box0\hskip\skip0
    \endgroup
}

1: \fbox{\hbox to 30pt{\null\hskip13pt\bul\hskip13pt\null}}  okay, too few space

2: \fbox{\hbox to 30pt{\null\hskip10pt\bul\hskip10pt\null}}  okay, space fits exactly

3: \fbox{\hbox to 30pt{\null\hskip7.5pt\bul\hskip7.5pt\null}}  okay, maximum stretch
\medskip

4: \fbox{\hbox to 30pt{\null\hskip11pt\bul\hskip11pt\null}}  wrong, still enough space left

5: \fbox{\hbox to 30pt{\null\bul\null}} wrong, too many bullets

\end{document}
```

`\bul` should, as I understand, output at most one `\textbullet` centered across the available space if there's some free horizontal space of 5pt up to 15pt. Here's the result:

[image]

On the first line there's only 4pt left, so no bullet occurs. On line 2 the bullet can take its natural width and fits exactly once. On the third line it needs to stretch to its maximum width. Those cases are fine. The ones I don't understand are on the next two lines.

Line 4 should leave a space of 8pt in which a bullet can fit quite comfortably. No bullet occurs, though. Why?

The opposite problem is on line 5. Here the maximum stretch is exceeded, hence TeX gives an `underfull \hbox` warning. But why does it output three boxes?

Section 9.3.3 of *TeX by Topic* explicitly states that you should use `\copy` with the various leaders commands to make sure the box register is not empty after it has been used first. Actually, this is exactly the effect I want to achieve, which is why I used `\box`. The output still has three bullets.

Could anyone explain why that is happening (and also how to fix it)?

Answer (score 2):

Glue with a nonzero stretch component will stretch to fill anyway, at the expense of badness.

In the fifth example, with `\showoutput`, you'd see

```latex
...\hbox(4.44444+0.0)x30.0, glue set 4.0
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\cleaders 10.0 plus 5.0 minus 5.0
.....\hbox(4.44444+0.0)x10.0, glue set 2.5fil
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
......\mathon
......\tensy ^^O
......\mathoff
......\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
```

where the glue stretch factor is 4. Hence the glue counts for 10+4*5=30 pt. No fix, this is how it is supposed to work.

Note: `\tensy` is because I typeset the thing with plain TeX to avoid irrelevant parts to show up.

With your document, the relevant diagnostic would be

```latex
..........\hbox(4.44444+0.0)x30.0, glue set 4.0
...........\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
...........\cleaders 10.0 plus 5.0 minus 5.0
............\hbox(4.44444+0.0)x10.0, glue set 2.5fil
.............\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.............\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 ^^O
.............\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
...........\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
```

Comment: When you write "No fix", do you also mean there's no way to define the desired `\bul` macro? Also, any ideas about line 4?

Comment: @siracusa In line 4 the space for the leaders is 8pt, which is less than the natural width of the leader box, so nothing shows up.

Comment: @siracusa If you want glue that stretches, but not more than a stated amount, well, you can't.

Comment: I'd be fine with glue that stretches more than the maximum amount, but I don't want the bullet to occur multiple times in that case

Comment: @siracusa You're out of luck, I'm afraid.